# How can I add buttons to Jquery UI dialog?

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using Jquery UI dialog box and I want to add a button. Can I use `.html()` as the function in the dialog?

```
$(".selector").dialog({
    buttons: [{
      text: "Ok",
      click: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    {
        text: "View Details",
        click: function () {
            $(this).html('Some HTML');
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: You want to add another button to the dialog when you click on the "View Details" button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `option` method to change the dialog's buttons on the fly. First use it with one argument to get the old buttons, modify that array, then use it with two arguments to change the buttons.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Ok",

            click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        {
            text: "View Details",
            click:function(){
                var buttons = $(this).dialog("option", "buttons");
                buttons.push({
                    text: "New button",
                    click: function() {
                        alert("New button clicked");
                    }
                });
                $( this ).dialog("option", "buttons", buttons);
            }
        }
    ]
});
```